# Meaning of HTTP request sampler data

Tags: java, jmeter

I just started using JMeter. For the time being, I am only interested in HTTP request sampler. There are a few terms that I think I understand, but I can't find official documentation that clarifies them. So, I would like to share my understandings and know if they are correct.

Let's take one single HTTP request case for example. Suppose at time `t0`, the request is sent from JMeter. At `t1`, JMeter starts to receive the response stream. At `t2`, JMeter receives the entire response stream. So, below are my understandings of the terms I find in the Graph Results output.

```
timestamp -> t0  
elapsed   -> t2 - t0  
latency   -> t1 - t0
```

So, are my understandings correct? If not, what should they be?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

> Latency . JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the
>   request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the
>   time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as
>   well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general
>   will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark)
>   measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the
>   interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is
>   experienced by a browser or other application client.

it's from here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html